# TryConvert doesn't get called when casting through object

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have a `DynamicObject` with an implemented `TryConvert` method. The following code works well:

```
dynamic d = GetMyDynamic();
int i = (int)d;   // TryConvert is called and returns the proper int value
```

However, when d is cast to object, the conversion fails at runtime:

```
object o = d;
int i = (int)o;  // TryConvert is not called. InvalidCastException thrown
```

Of course, `(int)(dynamic)o` does work, as expected.

Why is that? And is there any way to work around that so that `(int)o` will call `TryConvert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is actually pretty simple: If you don't use the `dynamic` keyword the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) is not used. But the Dynamic Language Runtime is what calls the `TryConvert` method.

Without the DLR, `o` is just an object of type `MyDynamicObject` that you are trying to cast to `int`. That fails, because `MyDynamicObject` is not an `int`.

Comment: Bummer. This means my users will need to cast to dynamic (I'm creating dynamic proxies on the fly, and my users aren't really aware of them).

Comment: @zmbq: That's not really a problem of dynamic at all. As Vyacheslav Volkov shows in his answer, you have the same problem if you return a "normal" type that has an explicit cast operator from a method with `object` as return type. Depending on what you are trying to achieve there are several different solutions. Maybe you can describe the end goal.

Comment: I'm creating a dynamic viewmodel that fires INotifyPropertyChanged events automatically by keeping a snapshot of the current values and periodically scanning for changes. The dynamic viewmodel returns dynamic proxy wrappers for each property. The user only encounters the proxies in IValueConverters - that's where WPF passes bound objects back to user code. I'd rather not force my users to cast to dynamic. While it's easy not to create a proxy for primitive types (it makes no sense anyway), it won't solve 100% of the problem.

Comment: The cool part, by the way, is automatically firing INotifyCollectionChanged events.

Comment: @zmbq: *"Periodically scanning for changes"*: This sounds like the wrong way to do it. Why not simply wrap the setter and raise the event when the property is set? The rest I don't understand. Why would you create a proxy for an int?

Comment: There's no reason to proxy an int, I just gave it as an example, the casting problem exists with every cast. Wrapping the setter as you suggested is what everybody does today. Non-trivial viewmodels that map classes from your business logic, require *a lot* of trivially implemented properties. It gets worse when your viewmodel has collections, forcing you to use an ObservableCollection *in your business logic layer*, or update view-related collections manually.

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with the Daniel Hilgarth. To better understand why this is so consider the example of an overload operators:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static explicit operator int(TestClass d)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

var testClass = new TestClass();
object obj = testClass;
var value = (int)testClass;//No exceptions here, because the CLR knows how to cast TestClass to int.
var i = (int)obj;//Exception here, because the CLR doesn't know how to cast object to int.
```